# How to parse numeric value in string representation in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, parsing, numbers

As the title.
I tested NSScanner, but it passed some strange strings. (ex :123aaa).
Is there any way to convert string<->number strictly?

Comment: What type of numbers? Integers? Floating point? What bases?

Comment: It was both of NSInteger and float. I solved classifying them by finding dot character(".").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily roll your own. Test whether the entire string was scanned, or whether there are additional characters.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:str];
int i;
if (![scanner scanInt:&i] || [scanner scanLocation] < [str length]) {
    // str contains additional characters
    ...
} else {
    // str contains only an int
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSScanner isn't that high-level. You'll have to validate the string yourself.

One way would be to scan characters up to the set of digits, assert that that failed, then scan the digits, then [scan to the end](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:) and assert that that failed.